# Search functionality in Restful Web services

Tags: mysql, rest, wcf

I am developing a search functionality in restful web service,from code i am passing searching string parameter to a method.i am getting the matched string response from database,Now how to validate whether input search string is exist or not from database.

```
 public MemberEntity Search(string prefix)
        {
            try
            {
                MemberEntity ObjMember = new MemberEntity();
                string sql = string.Format(@"select first_name, last_name from member_master where first_name like ('@prefix')");


                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(UtilityHelper.getConn()))
                {
                   //using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("select first_name, last_name from member_master where first_name like ('@prefix%')"), conn))
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql.ToString(), conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prefix", prefix);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                ObjMember.Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", dr["first_name"].ToString(), dr["last_name"].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return ObjMember;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            #endregion
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql should be like this.

```
string sql = string.Format(@"select first_name, last_name from member_master where first_name like '" + @prefix + "%'");
```